# LDAP with Spring

Tags: java, xml, active-directory

I want to use LDAP in my application in order to authenticate

I used in my previous config the database to authenticate

this is my previous config :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/test/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/test1/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />



         <form-login login-page="/index.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"
          default-target-url = "/test/MainHealthCertificat.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/index.htm?error=1"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.htm" />


    </http>


    <beans:bean class="com..CustomAuthenticationHandler" id="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"></beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>

                <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                                        users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from users where username=?"  
                    authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 
                />

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

this is my java class :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

 @Override
 public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

      String adminTargetUrl = "/test/mypage.htm";


      Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());


      if (roles.contains("ADMIN")) {  
         getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, adminTargetUrl);
      }else {
         super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

No I want to use ldap to authenticate

I modified **security-app-context.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

        <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/test/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/test1/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />



             <form-login login-page="/index.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"
              default-target-url = "/test/MainHealthCertificat.htm"
                authentication-failure-url="/index.htm?error=1"/>
            <logout logout-success-url="/index.htm" />


        </http>


        <beans:bean class="com..CustomAuthenticationHandler" id="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"></beans:bean>

         <security:authentication-manager>
         <security:ldap-authentication-provider 
           user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
           user-search-base="ou=users"
           group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
           group-search-base="ou=groups"
           group-role-attribute="cn"
           role-prefix="ROLE_">
         </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>

 <security:ldap-server url="ldap://192.168.0.88:389" manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system" manager-password="secret" />
    </beans:beans>
```

but when I test I have this error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db0
```

honestly I'm lost in settings ldap parameter : ou dc, cn,

I need help to configure the parameter of ldap  in security-app-context.xml

this is a correct parameter of ldap  which should be used in security-app-context.xml

**Base Provider URL**

ldap://192.168.0.88:389

**Base DN**

DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

**Principal**

CN=LDAP Requester,OU=Users,OU=Technical Accounts,OU=P9 Accounts,DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

**Credentials**

minister$9999

**Users**

**Authentication Search Filter**

(&(objectClass=person)(mail=@email_address@))

**Import Search Filter**

(objectClass=person)

**User Mapping**

**Screen Name**

sAMAccountName

**Password**

userPassword

**Email Address**

mail

**Full Name**

cn

**First Name**

givenName

**Middle Name**

middleName

**Last Name**

sn

**Group**

memberOf

**Groups**

**Import Search Filter**

(&(objectClass=group)(|(cn=MinisterUsers)(cn=MinisterAdministrateurs)(cn=Minister_*)))

**Group Mapping**

**Group Name**

cn

**Description**

sAMAccountName

**User**

member

**Export**

Users DN DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

Groups DN DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

Answer (score 0):

Error code **data 52e** means invalid credentials supplied.

Please try to remove these attributes **manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system" manager-password="secret"** 
in the below.

```
<security:ldap-server url="ldap://192.168.0.88:389" manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system" manager-password="secret" />
```

And give a try again. These are LDAP administration credentials and are not needed for the user authentication. User authentication are done using the values you supplied during login and spring by default try to Bind to LDAP using the provided details.

Also try to enable debug by including < debug />  tag in your security-app-context.xml and also add log4j.properties. This would give plenty of useful information for debuging.